# RDP session starts but remote window doesn't appear

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008, remote-access, remote-control, remote-connection

Yesterday I configured RDP on my machine and it worked fine. I closed the connection and that's all.

Today when I try to connect again I just get nothing. Credentials windows shows, I fill it (if I fill it wrong it says that logon was failed), then a session starts, but then if just is automaticly closing (or something like it). The last thing I see is the window below:
[image]

Target machine has Windows 10 as OS is it's important. And yesterday everything was working fine, and I didn't change anything in configuration of source or target machine.

Unable to access this machine at the moment

Comment: I don't know what to do. The last time I configured it I just checked that ports are opened and forwarded to machine, RDP option is enabled in "Remote Settings" and so on. I don't know what else can I do. Otherwise i will try it. But i don't.

Comment: Try rebooting the destination

Comment: I will do it in 5 hours, because now I don't have an access, this is why I needed remote...

Comment: I would recommend including this kind of information in the question itself. It helps to have perspective and also know what you have already tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time this issue can be solved by rebooting the destination machine.

Most probably there is hung session

***Workarounds***
[Remotely reboot the machine](http://www.howtogeek.com/109655/how-to-remotely-shut-down-or-restart-windows-pcs/)

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Well, windows decided to reinstall itself (it's an Insider build which is reinstalled while updating), and now I connect to it like a new machine (I get a trust verification messagebox while I always check "never ask me again about this machine"). Maybe restart could be enough, but I had no choice: W10 updates automaticly. Anyway, thanks for understanding, I didn't expect that session could just `hung` without any reason, in regular usage.